# Receiving wrong result from calculation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> The maximum heart rate is the highest heart rate obtained during maximum exercise. The difference in maximum heart rate depends on age and gender. There are simple methods to gauge your predicted maximum heart rate such as the formula 220 - your age = predicted maximum heart rate for a male. For instance, a 40-year-old male’s predicted maximum heart rate is 180 beats/minute.

The program will need to calculate the maximum heart rate for a male using the formula: 220-their age=maximum heart rate and: 212-their age=maximum heart rate for a female. The user must be able to input their age and select their gender and select their resting heart rate.
The program must then use this formula to determine your target heart rate:

Target Heart Rate = [(Maximum Heart Rate – Resting Heart Rate) × 80%]

The program must be able to display the use’s maximum heart Rate, resting heart rate and Target Heart Rate.

but for some reason im receiving when i run my program it does not seem to fully take in the inputs and gives me a wrong answer when the button is clicked for male it gives me the answer of 179.0 for male and 169.0 for female.

ive looked over and over it and cannot seem to figure out this logical error. here is my code.

```
public class MainHMR extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button chkCmd;
CheckBox Male, Femail;
EditText age, RestHeart;
TextView MaxHeart, TargetHeart;

int m = 220;
int f = 212;
int AgeResult =0, RestResultFinal =0, TargetHeartFinal =0;
double MaleResult, FemailResult;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_hmr);
    Initilise();
    format();
    Male.setOnClickListener(this);
    Femail.setOnClickListener(this);
    chkCmd.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void Initilise() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /* Button */chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    /* checkBox */Male = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbM);
    /* checkBox */Femail = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbF);
    /* EditText */age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    /* EditText */RestHeart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRestHeart);
    /* TextView */TargetHeart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etTargetHeard);
}

private void format() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String change = age.getText().toString();
    AgeResult = 0; // set it to 0 as the default
    try {
        AgeResult = Integer.parseInt(change);
        System.out.println(AgeResult);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){}

    String changeTwo = RestHeart.getText().toString();
    RestResultFinal = 0; // set it to 0 as the default
    try {
        RestResultFinal = Integer.parseInt(changeTwo);
        System.out.println(RestResultFinal);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){}
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bResults:
    if (Male.isChecked()) {
        int result = m - AgeResult;
        MaleResult = ((result - RestResultFinal) * 0.8);
        String finalResult = Double.toString(MaleResult);
        TargetHeart.setText(finalResult);
    } else if (Femail.isChecked()) {
        int result = f - AgeResult;
        FemailResult = (int) ((result - RestResultFinal) * 0.8);
        String finalResult = Double.toString(FemailResult);
        TargetHeart.setText(finalResult);
        break;
    }

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I could understand it if you were getting 176 for a male and 169 for a female... but not 179. Are you sure about that?

I *suspect* `Integer.parseInt` is failing for you - but you can't tell, because of this:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e){}
```

*Never* just catch an exception and completely ignore it. Put logging in there *at the very least*.

You're doing the same for both inputs. Why would you want to continue (and put up bogus data) if either parse operation failed? Surely you should just stop at that point, and inform the user that they should fix their input.

Next there's the way that you're performing the arithmetic. You're doing it all in *integer* arithmetic, but then using `Double.toString` - why? That's only ever going to give you a value ending in `.0`. If you want to *actually* get a non-integer result, you need to perform the arithmetic in floating point. e.g.

```
// I've changed the names of some variables to comply with conventions
double maximumRate = MALE_MAXIMUM_RATE_LIMIT - parsedAge;
double targetRate = (maximumRate - parsedRestingRate) * 0.8;
```

Comment: Yes sorry you were right about the outputs my mistake its 176.0 at the moment for male and 169.0 for femail.  I haven't implement anything to tell the user to fix there inputs yet as was going to add them in after.

Comment: i managed to get it sorted what i realised i was doing was trying to parse the data before i even inputted the data into the program. silly me thank you very much for your help i swiftly changed the variables to comply with the conversions as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Simple try using JOptionPane

```
public class HeartRates {

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int month,month1;
    private int day,day1;
    private int year,year1;


    public HeartRates(int mn, int dy,int yr)
    {
        month=mn;
        day=dy;
        year=yr;
    }

    public void setFname(String first)
    {
        fname=first;
    }

    public void setLname(String last)
    {
        lname=last;
    }

    public void setMonth(int mn)
    {
        month1=mn;
    }

    public void setDay(int dy)
    {
        day1=dy;
    }

    public void setYear(int yr)
    {
        year1=yr;
    }

    public String getFname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getLname()
    {
        return lname;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month1;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day1;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public int getYear1()
    {
        return year1;
    }

    public int personAge()
    {

        int age;
        age=getYear()-getYear1();

        return age;
    }

    public int maximumHeartRate()
    {
        int max;
        max=220-personAge();

        return max;
    }

    public String targetHR(){

        int hrMax;
        int hrMin;

        hrMax=(maximumHeartRate()*85)/100;
        hrMin=(maximumHeartRate()*50)/100;
        String message=String.format("Target Heart Rate range: %d~%d", hrMin,hrMax);
        return message;

    }

}

//MAIN 

import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class HeartRateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();   
        int cyear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
        int cmonth=now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cdate=now.get(Calendar.DATE);

        HeartRates myHeart=new HeartRates(cmonth,cdate,cyear);

        String fname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your First Name");
        String lname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Last Name");

        String mn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Birth Month(Enter Numerical Value)");
        String dy=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Birth Day");
        String yr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Birth Year");

        int month=Integer.parseInt(mn);
        int day=Integer.parseInt(dy);
        int year=Integer.parseInt(yr);

        myHeart.setFname(fname);
        myHeart.setLname(lname);
        myHeart.setMonth(month);
        myHeart.setDay(day);
        myHeart.setYear(year);

        int age=myHeart.personAge();
        int maxHR=myHeart.maximumHeartRate();
        String message=myHeart.targetHR();

        String msg=String.format("Name: %s %s\nAGE: %d\nMaximum Heart Rate: %d\n%s",fname,lname,age,maxHR,message);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);

    }
```